# Tensorflow LSTM example input format batches2string

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I'm following Udacity's LSTM tutorial but having a hard time understanding input data format of LSTM. https://github.com/rndbrtrnd/udacity-deep-learning/blob/master/6_lstm.ipynb

Can someone explain what num_unrolling in below code? or how to generate a training batch for the LSTM model?

```
batch_size=64
num_unrollings=10

class BatchGenerator(object):
  def __init__(self, text, batch_size, num_unrollings):
    self._text = text
    self._text_size = len(text)
    self._batch_size = batch_size
    self._num_unrollings = num_unrollings
    segment = self._text_size // batch_size
    self._cursor = [ offset * segment for offset in range(batch_size)]
    self._last_batch = self._next_batch()

  def _next_batch(self):
    """Generate a single batch from the current cursor position in the data."""
    batch = np.zeros(shape=(self._batch_size, vocabulary_size), dtype=np.float)
    for b in range(self._batch_size):
      batch[b, char2id(self._text[self._cursor[b]])] = 1.0
      self._cursor[b] = (self._cursor[b] + 1) % self._text_size
    return batch

  def next(self):
    """Generate the next array of batches from the data. The array consists of
    the last batch of the previous array, followed by num_unrollings new ones.
    """
    batches = [self._last_batch]
    for step in range(self._num_unrollings):
      batches.append(self._next_batch())
    self._last_batch = batches[-1]
    return batches

def characters(probabilities):
  """Turn a 1-hot encoding or a probability distribution over the possible
  characters back into its (most likely) character representation."""
  return [id2char(c) for c in np.argmax(probabilities, 1)]

def batches2string(batches):
  """Convert a sequence of batches back into their (most likely) string
  representation."""
  s = [''] * batches[0].shape[0]
  for b in batches:
    s = [''.join(x) for x in zip(s, characters(b))]
  return s

train_batches = BatchGenerator(train_text, batch_size, num_unrollings)
valid_batches = BatchGenerator(valid_text, 1, 1)

print(batches2string(train_batches.next()))
print(batches2string(train_batches.next()))
```

I understand there is a cursor. However, why do we throw away rest of the text other than first 10 characters (num_unrolling) of 64 batches?

You could point me to any resource or examples that could help me to understand the input format. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the purpose of the RNN you are training is to predict the next character in a string and you have one LSTM for each character position.
In the code above the cited code they have also made a mapping from a character to a number ' ' is 0, 'a' is 1, 'b' is 2 etc.  And this is further translated into '1-hot' encodings that is ' ' which is 0 is encoded as [1 0 0 0 ... 0], 'a' which is 1 as [0 1 0  0 ... 0], 'b'  as [0 0 1 0 0 ... 0]. In my explanation below I skip this mapping for clarity, so all my characters should really be numbers or actually 1-hot encodings.

Let me start with the simpler case, where 
batch_size = 1 and num_unrollings =1. 
Let us also say your training data is 
"anarchists advocate social relations based upon voluntary association of autonomous individuals mutu"

In this case your first character is the 'a' in anarchists and the expected output (label) is the 'n'. 
In the code this is represented by the return value of next().
batches = [ [ 'a' ], ['n' ]], where the first element of the list is the input and the last element is the label. 
This is then in step 0 fed into the RNN.
In the next step the input is 'n' and the label is 'a' (the third letter in 'anarchi...', so the next 
batches = [ ['n'], ['a'] ]
and the third step batches is 
batches = [ ['a'] , ['r']]
and so on. Notice how the last element (self._last_batch) in the inner list is the first element in the inner list at the next time-step (batches = [self._last_batch]).

This is if the num_unrollings = 1.
If num_unrollings = 5 then instead of only stepping one lstm unit forward every time you step num_unrolling=5 lstm units forward in every time-step. Thus the next function should provide the input for the 5 first RNN that is the 5 characters 'a','n','a','r','c' and also the corresponding labels 'n','a','r','c','h'. 
Notice the last four input characters are the same as the first 4 labels, so to be more memory efficient this is encoded as a list of the first 6 characters i.e.

batches = [ [ 'a'],['n'],['a'],['r'],['c'], ['h'] ],

with the understanding that the first 5 charaters are the input and the last 5 characters are the labels. and the  next time next is called next returns the input and labels for the next 5 lstms

batches = [ [ 'h'], ['i'], ['s'], ['t'], ['s'], [' '] ] ],
Notice the 'h' is also in this list as it before only was used as a label and now only is used as an input.

if batch_size > 1 you simoultaneously feed several sequences into the RNN update step. Notice here cursor is not a cursor but a list of cursors --- one for each sequence. consider now batch_size = 2.
In the above example where the trainingdata is the 100 characters "anarchists advocate social relations based upon voluntary association of autonomous individuals mutu" the second sequence of text simply starts in the middle
"luntary association of autonomous individuals mutu", so
the batches in the first step contain the information [ 'a','n','a','r','c', 'h'] and ['l','u','n','t','a','r'], corresponding to the same 6 first characters as before and the first 6 characters after the middle.
 but it is organized as follows (tranposed) 
batches = [ [ 'a', 'l'], ['n', 'u'], ['a', 'n'], ['r', 't'], [c', 'a'], ['h', 'r']]
the batches in the second time-step is 
contains the information [ 'h', 'i', 's', 't', 's', ' ' ] and  ['r','y', ' ', 'a', 's', 's'] , but again tranposed
batches = [[ 'h', 'r'], ['i', 'y'], ['s', ' '], ['t', 'a'], ['s', 's', [' ', 's'] ]
and so on.

The above is a technical answer to what num_unrollings means for the generation of the batches. However num_unrollings is also the number of characters you go back in the backpropagation part of the updating of the weights in the RNN.
This is so as in each time-step in the RNN learning algorithm you feed in num_unrolling input characters and you only calculate on the corresponding lstm's, while the (hidden) input from the previous part of the sequence is stored in variables that are not trainable. You may try to set the num_urollings to 1 and see whether it is harder to learn long range correlations. (you might need many timesteps).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a thorough answer.  I was racking my brain on this.  

`batches2string(train_batches.next())` shows the expected order (a list, `batch_order` length, of `num_unrollings+1` chars of `vocabulary_size` one-hots) .  

But, `train_batches.next()` just seemed convoluted.  It is a list `num_unrollings+1` long, each member is an array containing `batch_size` lists of `vocabulary_size` one-hot lists for letters.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It's great. There is one typo: last 5 characters -> last 1 character